# How to do a location based query on a firestore collection group

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to query documents from a firestore collection group that are within a certain geographic area. There are a couple libraries ([geo_firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/geo_firestore_flutter) and [geoFlutterFire](https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire)) that can do this for a collection but I'm looking to do it for a collection group. Any ideas how I can achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't it working the same way with a collection group?

Comment: No, the function expects a collection reference. But I've modified the library now to receive a collectionGroup, thanks